# Rails 4: html_safe for only specific tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to allow a couple specific tags like (`<br>`) but let rails continue to escape others. Html_safe does not appear to take any arguments. What's the smoothest way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The sanitize helper will html encode all tags and strip all attributes that aren’t specifically allowed.

```
sanitize @article.body, :tags => %w(br)
```

Link to [API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to sanitize a specific string. I did it:

```
white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
my_string = white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(my_string, tags: %w(br))
```

If you want the tag with only permitted attributes, do this:

```
my_string = white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(my_string, tags: %w(meta), attributes: %w(name content))
```

Very easy to use and powerful solution.

More information about [White List Sanitizer](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer).